# Vandemonder type determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\left|\begin{array}{cccccccccc}1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
x_1&x_2&x_3&\cdots&x_n\\
x_1^2&x_2^2&x_3^2&\cdots&x_n^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
x_1^{n-2}&x_2^{n-2}&x_3^{n-2}&\cdots&x_n^{n-2}\\
x_1^{n+1}&x_2^{n+1}&x_3^{n+1}&\cdots&x_n^{n+1}\end{array}\right|.\end{aligned}\end{equation*}$$

How to compute? If the last row is $x_1^n,\cdots$, it is easy by adding a line like $x_1^{n-1},\cdots$. But for this one, if we add two lines, I have not find the formula. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the determinant using the last row gives a combination of Vandermonde sub determinants and the formula is known for it. -i.e-
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1) ^{n+i-1} x_i^{n+1} \vert V_i\vert $$
such that $V_i$ is the sub matrix of $V$ removing the last row and $i$-th column
now each $V_i$ is a Vandermonde matrix and you can use the known formula.